# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Cannot assign requested address: how to increase the limit

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, centos7, lamp

We're using Lampp stack, PHP PDO, centos 7, MySQL 8. The database server and the MySQL server are different.

On long operations like file uploading, I get

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Cannot assign requested address
```

Per [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39509/mysql-pdo-cannot-assign-requested-address), I tried making the PDO connection persistent, didn't fix it. the other answer suggests increasing `max open files` in  `/etc/security/limits.conf` but I didn't find that option in that file.

How to fix that error? does editing that file or any file requires a server restart? Because it's a production server, I need to notify the team should any of the solution require a server restart